# R and SQL Connection

Tags: sql-server, r

I am trying to connect R with SQL using RODBC library

```
library(RODBC)
conn < - odbcDriverConnect("Driver=SQL Server; Server='userid\SQLEXPRESS'; Database=northwind")
queryResult <- sqlQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM orders")
dim(queryResult)
```

Its not allowing me to connect to SQL, giving error "\" character is not valid

Also can someone please tell me:
how can i save this information in  Excel workbook
can we apply functions like max(queryresult), etc on output

Comment: try Put @ in the begging of string ... like (@"Driver=SQL Server; Server='userid\SQLEXPRESS'; Database=northwind")

Comment: Try escaping the backslash with two: `userid\\SQLEXPRESS`